# How can I create external data source in BigQuery and connect to composer cloud sql?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer

We have a composer environment in GCP and we want to export the airflow database in the tenant project to BigQuery. Is there a way to do so?
[Composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFBuv.png)

Answer (score 1):

I searched in all the location of Composer (on GKE with the secret and the cloud SQL proxy), in the Airflow db connexion, I got all the required element to connect my external source to BigQuery and I got this error:

[image]

So, you can't.....

---

**EDIT 1:**

Firstly, you can use the automatically configured connexion

Then, use the MySqlOperator to request the database and do what you want. Sometime it's easier to use the MySqlHook.

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks for your reply! So I guess there is no way we can access to the airflow database? Actually we want to do some analysis and create some dashboards on these data.

Comment: You can't access to the DB though BigQuery (that was your question!). But, yes, you can access to the DB. You can also imagine that you create a dag that request the database with the analytics queries that you want and to store the result in BigQuery. Then plug Datastudio on the result stored in BigQuery

Comment: Thanks! That also works. I can create a dag to query the database and store it in bigquery. Can you show me how you can access to the db?